# trying to print to a text file with words that only have two or more occurring vowels

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
twovowels=re.compile(r".*[aeiou].*[aeiou].*", re.I)
nonword=re.compile(r"\W+", re.U)
text_file = open("twoVoweledWordList.txt", "w")
file = open("FirstMondayArticle.html","r")
for line in file:
    for word in nonword.split(line):
        if twovowels.match(word): print word
        text_file.write('\n' + word)
text_file.close()

file.close()
```

This is my python code, I am trying to print only the words that have two or more occurring vowels. When i run this code, it prints everything, including the words and numbers that do not have vowels, to my text file. But the python shell shows me all of the words that have two or more occurring vowels. So how do I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the vowels with str.translate and compare lengths. If after removing the letters the length difference is > 1 you have at least two vowels:

```
with open("FirstMondayArticle.html") as f, open("twoVoweledWordList.txt", "w") as out:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            if len(word) - len(word.lower().translate(None,"aeiou")) > 1:
                out.write("{}\n".format(word.rstrip()))
```

In your own code you always write the word as `text_file.write('\n' + word)` is outside the if block. a good lesson in why you should not have multiple statements on one line, your code is equivalent to:

```
   if twovowels.match(word):
        print(word)
    text_file.write('\n' + word) # <- outside the if
```

Your code with the if in the correct location, some changes to your naming convention, adding some spaces between assignments and using `with` which closes your files for you:

```
import re
with open("FirstMondayArticle.html") as f, open("twoVoweledWordList.txt", "w") as out:
    two_vowels = re.compile(r".*[aeiou].*[aeiou].*", re.I)
    non_word = re.compile(r"\W+", re.U)
    for line in f:
        for word in non_word.split(line):
            if two_vowels.match(word):
                print(word)
                out.write("{}\n".format(word.rstrip()))
```

Comment: Are you implying that copying and translating is cheaper than regex matching? I'd be interested to see numbers if that is so.

Comment: on the outside of the if, it still writes all of the words from the the html file to the text file :(

Comment: @Brando, that is my point, yours is outside the if, you would need to move it inside.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is outside of `if` condition. This is what the code lines should look like:

```
for line in file:
    for word in nonword.split(line):
        if twovowels.match(word):
            print word
            text_file.write('\n' + word)
text_file.close()

file.close()
```

Here is a [sample program on Tutorialspoint](http://goo.gl/dwghJ8) showing the code above is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an alternate, and simpler, method, not using `re`:

```
def twovowels(word):
    count = 0
    for char in word.lower():
        if char in "aeiou":
            count = count + 1
            if count > 1:
                return True
    return False

with open("FirstMondayArticle.html") as file,
        open("twoVoweledWordList.txt", "w") as text_file:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            if twovowels(word):
                print word
                text_file.write(word + "\n")
```

Comment: You could make `aeiou` a set of letters

Comment: @PadraicCunningham True, but for that small of a set, I'm not entirely sure that hashed lookup vs. linear search is a win...

Comment: If you have 1000000 words it will  make a difference, you can also `return sum(ch in "aeiou" for ch in word.lower() ) > 1`, create the set once and pass it to the function if necessary.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Hmm... yes. Many ways to skin that cat, I guess. Still, I was intending to err a bit on the side of readability/comprehension for a beginner. I actually like the `sum(...)` idea best, though...